# Hello I'm just wondering what PL/SQL Lexer error: Unterminated string means? I've been researching it but I cant seem to get it

Tags: plsql, plsqldeveloper

this is my code

```sql
DECLARE 
d_country_name VARCHAR2 (50); 
d_median_age NUMBER(6,2); 
BEGIN 
SELECT country_name, median_age INTO d_country_name, d_median_age 
FROM wf_countries 
WHERE country_name = ‘United States of America'); 
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(' The median age in '||d_country_name||' is '||d_median_age||'.'); 
END;
```

but it says

ORA-20001: Error at line 8, col85: PL/SQL Lexer error: Unterminated string

I cant seem to see whats wrong, thank you in advance!

Comment: You have a smart quote (`‘`) just before `United States of America`.  Replace this with a neutral quote `'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems incorrect first quote and extra parentheses after America'.